# catkin_make » /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcsparse

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to get LSD_SLAM working but when running the `catkin_make` command at 91% I get the error message `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcsparse`. 
I already tried to softlink using this command `sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libg2o_solver_csparse.so /usr/bin/lcsparse.so` but this doesn't fix it.

here is the full error message:

> [ 91%] Linking CXX shared library /home/adas/lsd-slam_workspace/devel/lib/liblsdslam.so
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcsparse
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> lsd_slam/lsd_slam_core/CMakeFiles/lsdslam.dir/build.make:755: recipe for target '/home/adas/lsd-slam_workspace/devel/lib/liblsdslam.so' failed
> make[2]: *** [/home/adas/lsd-slam_workspace/devel/lib/liblsdslam.so] Error 1
> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2385: recipe for target 'lsd_slam/lsd_slam_core/CMakeFiles/lsdslam.dir/all' failed
> make[1]: *** [lsd_slam/lsd_slam_core/CMakeFiles/lsdslam.dir/all] Error 2
> Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
> make: *** [all] Error 2
> Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed

To be honest I don't know that else I should try as there is nothing called lcsparse in apt either.

Best regards,
Alex

Software:
Ubuntu 18.04
ROS-Melodic
catkin_tools 0.4.5

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328720/catkin_make-%C2%BB-/usr/bin/ld:--cannot-find--lcsparse/) by [MrMinemeet](https://answers.ros.org/users/44067/mrminemeet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2019-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I opened an issue on Stackoverflow too.

Eventually found the solution myself.
Here is the link to Stackoverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57077832/catkin-make-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lcsparse/57092644#57092644

---

Originally posted by [MrMinemeet](https://answers.ros.org/users/44067/mrminemeet/) with karma: 41 on 2019-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0